# PyDev interactive console

Tags: python, pydev

When trying to open a interactive console on pydev I get an error:

> Error initializing console.
>   Unexpected error connecting to console.
>   Failed to recive suitable Hello response from pydevconsole. Last msg
>   received: HTTP server returned unexpected status: Service Unavailable
>   Command Line used:  D:\activestate\python.exe -u
>   D:\Boulot\pydev\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.3.3.201401272249\pysrc\pydevconsole.py
>   51203 51204 51203 51204

```
Eclipse:
Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627
Pydev:
PyDev for Eclipse   3.3.3.201401272249
Java:
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: What version of Eclipse, PyDv and Java are you using?

Comment: Answer in the question

Comment: possible duplicate of [PyDev Jython Interactive Console on Eclipse fails to be created](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20395750/pydev-jython-interactive-console-on-eclipse-fails-to-be-created)

Comment: I saw that, but I think it's a different problem for he gets unexpected status: null while I get unexpected status: Service Unavailable. Furthermore,  the accepted dolution does not seem to apply to me , as my LAN settings are disabled and therefore I cannot click on the Advanced button he suggests.

Comment: It could be an overly aggressive firewall blocking it though. PvDev talks to the interactive console's kernel via sockets. In other words the thing actually doing the back-end processing is not running directly embedded in the thing that is displaying it (which is how it can switch interpreters easily)

Comment: I have the same problem (Win 7, Eclipse Luna (4.4.0), Python 2.6.4 and 2.7.2, Java 1.7.0_55). Turned off my firewall, didn't make a difference.

Comment: Never mind, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21111262/897968) to the linked potential duplicate made it go away, even though I had been using the same setup for years without problem. Ah well, another mystery :)

Answer (score 7):

Try following:

In Eclipse under Window/Preferences/General/Network Connections:

--> set Active Provider: Manual

--> check in the box "Proxy bypass" if localhost and 127.0.0.1 are checked

Click Apply and try to open again.

That worked for me

Answer (score 2):

As documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176604/traitlets-traitlets-traiterror-in-pycharm), the solution is to update IPython

```
workon project
pip install -U ipython
```

I was having the same problem and fixed it with this.

Answer (score 0):

(My solution is inspired by @Sala's answer. And I want to add more reasoning here.)

### The root cause for my problem is, pydev console is hosted on localhost/127.0.0.1 and I have configured a proxy in my system. So my eclipse tried to visit it via a proxy but my proxy cannot find it since it is not a valid public address.

With @Sala's solution, `one` working configuration is like below. It essentially prevents eclipse from using the `system` (i.e. `native`) proxy.

[image]

And you should notice that in the `Proxy bypass` area, the Provider for `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` is `Manual`. Just in consistent with the `Proxy entries` area.

### But what if you do want to use proxy? You need to bypass your native proxy for pydev console.

You can do it in IE -> Internet Options -> Connection -> LAN Settings -> Advanced:

[image]

Then, you don't nee to restart your eclipse, and you will see the Provider for the *bypassed* `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` has changed to `Native` now as shown below:

[image]

Now the pydev console should be able to start.