# traitlets.traitlets.TraitError in Pycharm

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, console, pycharm

I am a beginner in python. I am facing the following problem.

Whenever I start pycharm Community edition (version 5.0.3), the Python console fails to starts and shows the following error:

```
usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/lib/pycharm-community/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py 53192 49994 
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/usr/lib/pycharm-community/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 488, in <module>
    pydevconsole.StartServer(pydev_localhost.get_localhost(), int(port), int(client_port))
  File "/usr/lib/pycharm-community/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 330, in StartServer
    interpreter = InterpreterInterface(host, client_port, threading.currentThread())
  File "/usr/lib/pycharm-community/helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython_console.py", line 26, in __init__
    self.interpreter = get_pydev_frontend(host, client_port)
  File "/usr/lib/pycharm-community/helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 472, in get_pydev_frontend
    _PyDevFrontEndContainer._instance = _PyDevFrontEnd()
  File "/usr/lib/pycharm-community/helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 303, in __init__
    self.ipython = PyDevTerminalInteractiveShell.instance()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/configurable.py", line 354, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 328, in __init__
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 483, in __init__
    self.init_readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 1816, in init_readline
    if self.readline_use:
  File "/home/vivekruhela/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 529, in __get__
    return self.get(obj, cls)
  File "/home/vivekruhela/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 507, in get
    % (self.name, obj))
  traitlets.traitlets.TraitError: No default value found for None trait of <pydev_ipython_console_011.PyDevTerminalInteractiveShell object at 0x7f7b0e682cd0>

Process finished with exit code 1
Couldn't connect to console process.
```

How can I connect to the pycharm console? I have already installed IPython in my system.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue after installing pgcontents

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue.
I solved this by **updating ipython**.

My version was 3.1.0, upgrading it to 4.1.1 solved it.

in my case:

```
workon project
pip install -U ipython
```

Comment: I have tried your way but it doesn't work. first it shows ** workon: command not found**  and for second it works but still same error shows in pycharm python console.

Comment: 'workon' is used if you use virtual environement. Don't bother about this line. Have you tryed restarting pycharm ?

Comment: I have tried and I have tried re-installing also but problem still persist and one more thing is pycharm when started takes lot of time to load and every time it updats index and try to connect to python console and after some time an error come shown above.

Comment: I've had this issue also, updating ipython has not seemed to do the trick

Comment: Unfortunately, for python2.x there is no ipython version above 2.x

Answer (score 11):

I've found that this happened because I had installed ipython version 4.x, and then reverted to 3.2.0, without uninstalling the traitlets more advanced version first. This did the trick then:

```
pip uninstall ipython[all]
pip uninstall traitlets
pip install ipython==3.2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this was due to a conflicting installation of IPython through `pip` and `apt`. Removing the `apt`-installed version using `sudo apt remove ipython` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I initially tried unsuccessfully by trying

```
pip install -U ipython
```

But then tried following and it worked:

```
pip uninstall ipython[all]
pip uninstall traitlets
pip install ipython
```

Thanks @mirandes