# Pydev: error initializing console

Tags: eclipse, pydev, jython

I can't get the Jython console to work in Eclipse Luna.  The Python console works.

The error message is:

> Error initializing console.
>   Unexpected error connecting to console.
>   Failed to recive suitable Hello response from ...

The problem and a solution is described here:[proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20395750/pydev-jython-interactive-console-on-eclipse-fails-to-be-created)

The solution describes a fix in XP which i've tried to follow in Windows 7 though the steps are not exactly the same as described..

I had to check 'use a proxy server' and then add the 'localhost', ... to the exceptions.

I still get the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyDev interactive console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355359/pydev-interactive-console)

Answer (score 0):

Briefly speaking, you may need to change your network proxy setting for eclipse.
For a detailed answer, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355359/pydev-interactive-console/35953122#35953122).